# Setdiff R command equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r

is there an equivalent of the `setdiff()` R function in the python library `pandas` ?

I need to replicate a function like `setdiff(x, y)` that one can find in R!

Comment: `[a for a in x if not x in y]`?

Comment: There is a datatype `set` in python generally supporting usual set operations.

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry for reasking but how do I cnvert it from a set to a list again ? set seems like a dict....:-)

Comment: @AndreaFerrante set is not like a dictionary because there are no key-values pairs, just sets of values and you convert it to a list like this `list(a)`

Comment: Thanks a million I forgot it for a second !

Comment: Np good luck! https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp